# Why doesn't Azure AD support a default domain for signin

Tags: azure-active-directory

In single-tenant scenarios, why does Azure AD sign in require that the user provide the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can have multiple domains registered in AAD,
and most organizations have users with more than one domain name.
When you log in, you must specify your user principal name.
Same as when logging in to on-prem AD, you'd use e.g. CONTOSO\username or username@contoso.com.
Setting a default is not possible, and is usually not desired.

Comment: In a few instances, customers have asked for this and I had no clear technical reason. Supporting a default domain doesn't remove the ability to support others. But the vast majority of users are going to be using a common domain, why not allow default. What technically prevents this?

Comment: I don't work at Microsoft so I can't say for sure, but I think there is no technical blocker for not being able to do that. So that when you enter first.last it assumes it meant first.last@company.com. Just that it is not a highly-requested feature :) People are fine entering their whole usernames and maybe do not want it to be ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what I should be looking at is Azure AD B2C.
From this MSFT [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs):

> What are local accounts in Azure AD B2C? How are they different from
>   work or school accounts in Azure AD? In an Azure AD tenant, users that
>   belong to the tenant sign-in with an email address of the form
>   @. The  is one of the verified
>   domains in the tenant or the initial <...>.onmicrosoft.com domain.
>   This type of account is a work or school account.
>
> In an Azure AD B2C tenant, most apps want the user to sign-in with any
>   arbitrary email address (for example, joe@comcast.net, bob@gmail.com,
>   sarah@contoso.com, or jim@live.com). This type of account is a local
>   account. We also support arbitrary user names as local accounts (for
>   example, joe, bob, sarah, or jim). You can choose one of these two
>   local account types when configuring identity providers for Azure AD
>   B2C in the Azure portal. In your Azure AD B2C tenant, click Identity
>   providers and then select Username under Local accounts.